# Cannot resolve parameter 'X`1[Y]

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, interface, autofac

I'm working on a project where I work with weather model data. The models are different, but the logic of function calls within each different model is the same. Each model has a load of data generated about it, and then given the command to "run".

I have a service which is a request to get the load of data it needs to run, before a function called `Run` is called. This `run` function is common to all models, so I developed one interface called `IIndividualModelRunService`. But I've hit a problem. This issue exists no matter which of the models you are working with.

I used to have this constructor:-

```
public HRRRModelQueryService(IHRRRModelQueryRequestService hrrrModelQueryRequestService, IIndividualModelRunService modelRunService)
{
    _hrrrModelQueryRequestService = hrrrModelQueryRequestService;
    _modelRunService = modelRunService;
}
```

The IIndividualModelRunService has three implementations, one for each model, which do different model-specific stuff. I noticed after a while, it seemed to only eve be calling one of the three, no matter which path I had gone in the project, e.g. through Model1 code, Model2 code or Model3 code.

The above compiles and runs, albeit incorrectly.

I've tried updating the constructor to this, passing the type in `IIndividualModelRunService, in the hope specifying the service I want it to call will help:-

```
public HRRRModelQueryService(IHRRRModelQueryRequestService hrrrModelQueryRequestService, IIndividualModelRunService<HRRRModelRunService> modelRunService)
{
    _hrrrModelQueryRequestService = hrrrModelQueryRequestService;
    _modelRunService = modelRunService;
}
```

But I now get this exception on project load, and I suspect it is something I am not registering correctly:-

> None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'ModelRunDownloader.Domain.GFS.GFSModelQueryService' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:
>   Cannot resolve parameter 'ModelRunDownloader.Domain.ModelService.IIndividualModelRunService'1[ModelRunDownloader.Domain.GFS.GFSModelQueryService] modelRunService' of constructor 'Void .ctor(ModelRunDownloader.Domain.GFS.IGFSModelQueryRequestService, ModelRunDownloader.Domain.ModelService.IIndividualModelRunService'1[ModelRunDownloader.Domain.GFS.GFSModelQueryService])'.

In my container builder, I go get all assemblies that are prefixed with my project name, which works correctly as I've tested this, and then written the following commands:-

```
var assemblyList = assemblies.ToArray();

builder.RegisterAssemblyModules(assemblies);
builder.RegisterByAttributes(assemblies);        
builder.RegisterInstance(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()).As<_Assembly>();

return builder.Build();
```

I'm just wondering if I need to manually specify something here because of passing in that type into the interface, or whether I am on the wrong route totally? Quite new to autofac, so any feedback much appreciated!

Comment: It's unclear, are you saying your code uses multiple implementations of that interface at run time? Or is it always one? An IoC container cannot know which one you want. I don't know about autofac but typically you can register multiple concrete types to one interface if you name them, but then you have to resolve it manually (service locator) instead of DI.

Comment: I'd recommend you to create a small [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), because so far it seems that you just do not register `IIndividualModelRunService<HRRRModelRunService>` or its [generic](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/registration.html#open-generic-components) version in your modules